# I sent data over 900 dataset rows to the web api causing time out. Using Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to send it divided by 100 rows in a row. I don't have the knowledge to be amputated. C #
This is the code I use to call the web api.

```
public static string AddPlanningAPI(string planNo, string jobNo, string bDate, string eDate, string progId, string timeGroup, string userId, string stationId)
{
    DataSet ds = dsConfirmBookingAPI(planNo, jobNo, bDate, eDate, progId, timeGroup, userId, stationId);

    RSWSJobOrder.DataJobOrderSoapClient rsWsJobOrder = new RSWSJobOrder.DataJobOrderSoapClient();

    try
    {        
        string iResult = rsWsJobOrder.AddPlaning_Return_JsonString(ds, userId);
        return iResult;
    }
    catch (Exception tmp_ex) { throw tmp_ex; }
}



public string AddPlaning_Return_JsonString(System.Data.DataSet SendDs, string createBy) {
            return base.Channel.AddPlaning_Return_JsonString(SendDs, createBy);
        }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Please take your time to write your problem or detail exactly what the issue is. Also we've got no idea what `AddPlaning_Return_JsonString` is doing either.

Comment: The data that I submit is 941 rows. I would like to divide by 100 rows at a time.

Comment: See below. If I understood correctly you want to 'batch' upload items in groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you basically want to batch upload your rows. Below will achieve that, you'll define the number of items per 'batch' and upload them in those groups.

Please refer to comments in code for explanation of each line.

Note: If your DataTable needs a name (or you have multiple tables in `DataSet`) you'll need to modify the below to accommodate for those requirements.

```
public void BatchUpload(DataSet ds)
    {
        int numberPerBatch = 100;   //  Define the number per batch

        for (int skip = 0; skip < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; skip += numberPerBatch)  //  Group the batches
        {
            DataTable batchDT = new DataTable();    //  Create a new DataTable for the batch
            var batch = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().Skip(skip).Take(numberPerBatch);  //  LINQ to create the batch off existing set.

            foreach (var row in batch)  //  Import rows to new datatable
            {
                batchDT.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            DataSet batchDS = new DataSet();    //  Create a new DataSet
            batchDS.Tables.Add(batchDT);    //  Add datatable to dataset

            string iResult = rsWsJobOrder.AddPlaning_Return_JsonString(batchDS, userId);    //  send the batch off
        }
    }
```